# Update kernel to 4.1.1 in Ubuntu Mini

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu Mini 15.04 and I want to update the kernel to the latest 4.1.1. I've been looking online but there are so many different ways. I've tried some but always ran into some error.

I am not using a GUI, just command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install the initramfs tools before we being so that we can update the kernel properly.

```
sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools
```

Create a new temp folder that we can use for the time being for installation:

```
mkdir /kernel_tmp
```

Go to your `/kernel_tmp` folder, and run the following lines to download the kernel.

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.1-unstable/linux-headers-4.1.1-040101-generic_4.1.1-040101.201507011435_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.1-unstable/linux-headers-4.1.1-040101_4.1.1-040101.201507011435_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.1-unstable/linux-image-4.1.1-040101-generic_4.1.1-040101.201507011435_amd64.deb
```

then from the `/kernel_tmp` folder type in

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb
```

Then we need to update the `initramfs` for the new kernel:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

Then update the grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot when completed, it should be up to kernel 4.1.1.

Comment: It doesn't say 4.1.1 when I type in uname -r. It's still on 3.19.0-21-generic. I did everything you said. Typed in cd /tmp -> the lines you typed -> sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb -> reboot. I ran into no errors while doing this. What went wrong?

Comment: @c.C type in `sudo update-grub` and see if it makes the 4.1.1 kernel the first one.   I have run this many times on my Ubuntu installation when installing the 4.0.x kernels.

Comment: I ran that and rebooted. Still the same.

Comment: The 3.19 and 4.1.1 header folders/files are in usr/src if it helps.

Comment: @c.C It could be the mini version is missing the scripts that run parts of the update.  I just updated my answer.  I am thinking that the `update-initramfs` was not run when the new kernel was installed like it does on a full Ubuntu installation.

Comment: It can't find folders/files when I run that.

Comment: @c.C try it as `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all` it will create boot img files of all kernel versions on the system

Comment: @c.C ah, run `sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools` then run it.

Comment: It said initramfs-tools is already installed. I'm supposed to be in tmp when I run update-initramfs, right?

Comment: @c.C it should be in the path.  If not, you can run it manually by `sudo /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -c -k all`

Comment: Sorry if I mislead you, but initramfs is installed and in that directory. The problem is when I run the command, I get this: http://i.imgur.com/F1xtwB5.png

Comment: @c.C Ah, OK.  We need to download the kernel again.  Step by step.  Maybe create a folder for it like /kernel_tmp.  I will update my notes for that.  The problem with using tmp like this, is that on the reboot it deleted the files we downloaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25430/discussion-between-terrance-and-c-c).